# single sign on using active directory in asp.net

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows, adfs

I have lot's of database, so for secure authentication I want to put single sign on using the concept of active directory.

After reading of lot's of material i will try to install ADFS 2.0

But i can't do this because there is an error.which has following description

I have **Windows Active Server 2008 R2**..and this is version of it 6.1.7601 service pack 1 build 7601. .And for install adfs I use this version: W2K8R2\amd64.

I found this error:

**"ADFS 2.0 cannot be installed on this operating system version."**

So what should i do..?

For solving this problem i read most of articles from MSDN but i can't get proper help. And give me also information about:

```
How to install adfs.. step by step..
With use of adfs how i can put single sign on in my project..?
```

Understand me this procedure with suitable examples. And my project is in ASP.NET. For database I use SQL Server 2008 and LINQ.

What should I do to avoid the error? An example would be very helpful!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a SKU as listed in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974408. Go to Control Panel\System and Security\System and ensure its not anything else.

e.g. Some SKUs such as "Windows server 2008 standard without hyper-V" are not supported even if you are using the "correct" AD FS 2.0 download.

Comment: can u explain me in brief...i can't get it...plss give me one suitable example...

Comment: CAN ANYBODY GIVE ME STEPS FOR THAT HOW TO INSTALL OR PUT ACTIVE DIRECTORY ON MY SERVER